# What is the term Flc in LM27402?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, frequency, texas-instruments, compensation

[image]

Hi while going through LM27402 IC, inorder to find compensate components of cc1,cc2 and so on, there is term called Flc, can anyone explain what it is?

Comment: The inductor and capacitor create two complex poles at a frequency described by fLC.

Comment: `can anyone explain what it is?` It's explained a bit in the datasheet, but it may not be that simple to give a detailed explanation for someone here. In order to fully understand what it is and its effect(s), you need to have a control theory background: Closing the loop, stability, poles, zeroes, and the effect of poles/zeroes positions on stability, etc.